# Backbone Marionette routing and clearing resources

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, marionette

I am currently writing a Backbone Marionette with two sub-modules - (module - controller,model,view, layout).

Let's say one module is for displaying the latests news on the site, and the second is for showing the list of users that are registered.
The news module have a route that is registered to `/news` and user list is registered to `/users`.

When I move to the users page everything works fine - I have my users layout which is changing the view of the page, and a users collection is being fetched, everything works!

My problem is, the 'news' controller,views,layouts and models/collections are still in the memory while I don't need them.

What should I do in order to really clear the resources when I am changing between controllers?

Comment: It all depends on how you have coded your views, controllers and collections. all items will remain in memory and will not be collected as long as a live object is holding a reference to them. You really need to provide a code sample to get more detailed answer.